# how to write out the content list of derived classes

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I've a list

```
List <RootClass> classes = new List<RootClass>();
```

RootClass is an abstract class out of which i derive two other classes: SubClass1, and SubClass2.
in the program i create new classes in the following way:

```
classes.Add(new SubClass1(arg1, arg2));
classes.Add(new SubClass2(arg1, arg2));
```

Lets say now I have 20 of SubClass1, and 20 SubClass2 in the classes List.
How do I for example write out a field for all of the instances of SubClass1 in the list?

I tried:

```
foreach(SubClass1 sc1 in classes){
    Console.WriteLine(sc1.field1);
}
```

but it seems the compiler tries to cast each object in the list whether it's a type SubClass1 or SubClass2, so it throws a cast exception, when it attempts to do so with a type SubClass2.

I also did:

```
foreach (RootClass rc in classes){
if (rc is Subclass1){
    SubClass1 sc1 = rc as SubClass1;
    ConsoleWriteLine(sc1.field1);
}
}
```

it works fine with the latter solution, the problem is, in the program I'am writing I have to repeat this many times, each time modifying different fields, in different ways, so my question is is there a more profound way of doing this?

Comment: What is the responsibility of `List<RootClass>`?

Comment: you can use `OfType`, example: `foreach (var sub in classes.OfType<SubClass1>())`

Comment: It may make more sense to maintain a list for each `Subclass` if you frequently need these partial lists and just iterate all of them when you need the full list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OfType` extension method

```
foreach (var sub in classes.OfType<SubClass1>()) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(sub .field1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = classes.OfType<subtype>();
```